# Validate .tar file upload in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have this code

```
$inputs    = Input::all();
$file      = Input::file('file');
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'file' => 'required|max:50000|mimes:application/x-tar',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {

    $messages = $validator->messages();
    dd($file,$messages); <<<< --- keep executing 


    return Redirect::to('/vnf-packages/create')->withErrors($validator)->withInput()
    ->with('error','Something is wrong with your upload image');
} else {
..
}
```

I don't know why it kept getting into the fail block.
I did upload the file with `.tar`.

Am I missing anything in my codes ?

---

## Updated

as you can see, I did upload the .tar file

```
dd($file,$messages);
```

---

```
UploadedFile {#446 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "config-vnfp-vyos-567.tar"
  -mimeType: "application/x-tar"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "/private/var/tmp"
  filename: "phpNaZGxr"
  basename: "phpNaZGxr"
  pathname: "/private/var/tmp/phpNaZGxr"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/private/var/tmp/phpNaZGxr"
  aTime: 2020-03-09 15:10:28
  mTime: 2020-03-09 15:10:28
  cTime: 2020-03-09 15:10:28
  inode: 14703131
  size: 140
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 70
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}
MessageBag {#454 ▼
  #messages: array:1 [▼
    "file" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "The file must be a file of type: tar."
    ]
  ]
  #format: ":message"
}
```

---

## Updated 2

```
'file' => 'required|max:50000|mimes:tar', //fail 
'file' => 'required|max:50000|mimes:application/x-tar', //fail 
'file' => 'required', //success
```

Comment: try this one it may help `file' => 'required|max:50000|mimes:tar'`

Comment: That is the first thing, I tried actually, and it keep getting into the fail section.

Comment: really looks weird, try to remove the size limit for now and try again

Comment: I tried remove the max attribute, still show the same error, some how , it doesn't detect the .tar.

Comment: What is the file size?

Comment: Also include the full controller method including signature.

Comment: @cyber8200 Can you try with `'file' => 'required|mimes:tar',` or `'file' => 'required|mimetypes:application/x-tar` ?

Comment: Was just about to suggest that. `mimetypes` takes MIME types as argument, while `mimes` takes extensions.

Comment: @vivek_23, that still failng `'file' => 'required|mimes:tar',`

Comment: what message do you have ? why validation fails ? I dont think its due to mme type if you are using `mimes:tar`

Comment: In your update you said you've tried `mimes:application/x-tar` but it should be `mimetypes:application/x-tar`.

Comment: Can you dump those two, `ini_get('post_max_size')` and `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to test an upload with a `.tar` file and when I use the `getMimeType` method, it returns the following:

```
application/gzip
```

So your validation rule should be:

```php
'file' => 'required|mimetypes:application/gzip',
```

If you want to use the `mimes` rule, you'd want something like this:

```php
'file' => 'required|mimes:gz',
```

And with some research, I've found the following: https://superuser.com/questions/901962/what-is-the-correct-mime-type-for-a-tar-gz-file

You can find more information about how the validator validates these two rules in `Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php`.

The `validateMimes` method use the file's `guessExtension()` method, which returns `gz`.

```php
$value->getPath() !== '' && in_array($value->guessExtension(), $parameters)
```

And the `validateMimeTypes` method check use the file's `getMimeType()` method which returns `application/gzip`.

```php
return $value->getPath() !== '' &&
    (in_array($value->getMimeType(), $parameters) ||
    in_array(explode('/', $value->getMimeType())[0].'/*', $parameters));
```